# Finding the maximum value in all files within a directory

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to save the largest value in each text file in a directory into one list? I have multiple text files in the same format where each value is on a different line:

(first score)

(second score)

(third score)

I want to save the largest of these three integers into a list, and the same for all the other files in the folder. Is this possible?

Comment: wow thats very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

That's a way to do it.

```
import os

scores = []
for path in os.listdir("path"):
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        continue
    with open(path) as scores_file:
        scores.append(max(int(n.strip()) for n in scores_file))
```

You iterate over all files in the directory, strip the lines, turn them into an int and take the max out of it.

Comment: It produces an error (FileNotFoundError) even though I used the same path earlier on in my program, where I made a list of all the file names in the folder, so I dont think the path is incorrect. I'm a little bit confused. The problem is this line: "with open(path) as scores_file:".

Comment: @Eric `os.listdir()` makes a list of all files in the program. Did you do it on the directory path?

Comment: what do you mean by "in the program"? The path I used is the path to the folder with the files in it.